# How to load data frame in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I realise this is prolly a very basic question but I've searched around and can't work out how to do it.

When I open RStudio shown along with the various scripts above the top left window are two matrices I was working with in the last session "x" and "y". They are shown with a "excel" like symbol beside them. How can I load these into the current workspace?

Baz

[image]

Comment: just guessing, but they probably got saved in `.RData` and automatically reloaded when you re-opened RStudio.  Do you know that they're *not* currently loaded?

Comment: Read the documentation of RStudio [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/categories/200035113-Documentation).

Comment: Well they are not showing in the current workspace and when I type x or y I get: Error: object 'x' not found

Comment: If they were saved as an .Rdata file what would this file be called?

Comment: it would be called, literally, `.RData`

Comment: I hate to ask, but could you post a screenshot?

Comment: No probs see edited question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility.

The view you see in the top right window is not updated automatically when you change your data. So for example, if you have a df called `x` and view it, then remove it, the view is still displayed but `x` is gone.

So in the screenshot below, the environment is empty (no objects at all), but x is still displayed.

[image]

Comment: Ah OK I', not sure if I saved the session when I shut the machine down last night, I just turned the machine off using the start button. There does not appear to be an .RData file either.